# journald: extract part of a system journal into the journald format (i.e. for use with journalctl)

Tags: journald, journalctl

I have a situation where it would be really useful to attach the relevant bits of the system logs to a bug ticket. The system in question uses *journald* and I rather like using *journalctl* to inspect the logs, so what I'd like to do is extract the relevant time span of the system logs into a file so I later can use `journalctl --file=foo.journald` to inspect. Something like:

```
journalctl  -S @1500253701 -U @1500256701 -o export > foo.journald
```

except of course that the [export file format](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/export/) can't be read by *journalctl*.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `systemd-journal-remote` to convert like this

```
journalctl -S @1500253701 -U @1500256701 -o export > foo.export
systemd-journal-remote --output=foo.journald foo.export
journalctl --file=foo.journald
```

This information was added to the man page of `journalctl` in systemd 233, see [commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/72d17ce680a22b958b4c074f62d9fa44bc1f54e0).